Web Scraping with Selenium
I'm trying to to do a script in python that uses selenium to retrieve some information from this website. It seems that Cloudfare blocks the script because it is a bot. Here i post part of the code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
         "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
  }
        
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://worldwide.espacenet.com/")
advanced_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( lambda x: x.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/nav/ul/li[5]/label/span")) #toggle to be triggered to enter in advanced search mode
advanced_search.click()

Cloudfare block the page instantly and asks the user to verify that he is a human. Are there some ways to make the website think it is interacting with a real user or some options to add directly in the selenium webdriver?
I also tried to add a script that moves the mouse randomly on the window
EDIT: i want to use library under MIT or Apache license, so i cannot use undetected_chromedriver, even if it works well. Thanks
